# NSDateFormatter formats hours in range out of 0-24 with some international settings

Tags: ios, date, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

One specific Date and Locale configuration of iOS makes `NSDateFormatter` to have a really strange behaviour. It ignores my format strings and formats hours with value out of 0-24 range.

```
#define DATE_FORMAT "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @DATE_FORMAT;
return [formatter stringFromDate:value];
```

With custom format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` it returns dates like this "2016-05-26 **197**:33:17 PM +0000"

There is no `'T'` character between date and time parts and 197 hours...

`NSDateFormatter` with custom format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` can't parse string "2016-05-26T07:32:57" and returns `nil`.

This happens not only with my custom formatters. Internal Foundation formatters responsible for `description` suffer from this problem either:

```
(lldb) po value.description
2016-05-27 44:20:27 AM +0000
```

[image]
[image]

I reproduce this behaviour with specific system Regional settings on iOS 9.3.2:

```
"General">"Date & Time">"24-Hour Time" OFF
"General">"Date & Time">"Set Automatically" OFF
"General">"Date & Time">"Time Zone" Moscow

"General">"International">"Language" Русский (Russian)
"General">"International">"Prefferred language order" Русский (Russian), English (U.S.)
"General">"International">"Regional Format"  Russia
"General">"International">"Calendar" Gregorian
```

[image]
[image]

This is the only configuration I know for now that makes formatters work this way.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I'll appreciate any ideas how to analyse this because I don't have my own.

Comment: What happens if you set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`?

Comment: As rmaddy suggests, whenever setting ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date, always use locale of `en_US_POSIX`. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Thank you! 

Next line fixed everything:
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment of rmaddy and Rob the right solution in this situation is to specify "en_US_POSIX" locale for all formatters involved in serialisation NSDate objects.

So snipped posted in question part should be:

```
#define DATE_FORMAT "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @DATE_FORMAT;

formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

return [formatter stringFromDate:value];
```

For everybody who have same issue link posted by Rob would be extremely useful.
[See Technical Q&A 1480.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) I would recommend you to read it before applying this solution to your code.